# Inverse distance weighting on a bent matrix

Tags: algorithms, interpolation

Is it possible for IDW algorithm to account for a bend in a matrix? What I mean by the bend, is that the left and the right side of the matrix would be connected ( neighbors )

Let's say we have this 4x4 matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

And then the value at index `[2,3]` becomes 2

\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

We would interpolate to

\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 2
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Sure, you would just have to change the notion of distance to account for the modified connectivity, and then you can do inverse distance weighting as usual.

Comment: Oh, would I just have to add conditions that would check whether x > x1 and x < x1 and act accordingly? @Rahul

Comment: Oh, would I just have to add conditions that would check whether x > x1 and x < x1 and act accordingly?

Comment: Sort of. The simplest thing I would do is to just check the distance from x to x1, x1+n, and x1-n and take the minimum of the three.

Comment: Turns out it did work, my algorithm was wrong...